# Poetry fails to install NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, python-wheel, python-poetry

I am on ubuntu 18.04, python 3.8.10, poetry 1.1.14.

I'd like to add numpy to a package:

`poetry add numpy`

This fails with error:

```
  • Installing numpy (1.23.1): Failed

  EnvCommandError

  Command ['/home/vberenz/VirtualEnv/pam/bin/pip', 'install', '--no-deps', 'file:///home/vberenz/.cache/pypoetry/artifacts/2e/7e/aa/cdca3c9a6faeb4a552ccb55cc3c33734910b052e4a73c19822df994ca4/numpy-1.23.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl'] errored with the following return code 1, and output: 
  numpy-1.23.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Comment: Try to `/home/vberenz/VirtualEnv/pam/bin/pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: @phd I will give it a try, but I'd like to understand the reasoning: poetry is somehow related to pip ?

Comment: `pip` is **the** program that installs Python packages. All other programs — `pipenv`, `pipx`, `poetry`, whatever — are just convenience wrappers. They use `pip` under the hood.

Comment: poetry seems to be working by attempting to download the manylinux, but there is a mismatch with your OS (https://pypi.org/project/numpy/1.23.1/#files). You could open an issue on the poetry Github page if you still have this issue with the latest poetry (1.3.1). I believe there is also an option to select the sdist (tar.gz) to build from source, but I couldn't find the command on a quick search